# Python learning resources

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new here and I was wondering if anyone could refer me to some python learning resources for complete beginners in coding. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Mr Google might be of some help.

Comment: https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) is what I read back when I was learning how to program the language; and taking a class at a local college. It really dives into pretty much everything you'll need to know about the language. I really wish I would have bought [this nutshell book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100469.do) instead, though. You can always browse the web for some tutorials; or even just read some Python code. I heard Bill Gates learned at least some of his programming skills through reading the trashed printouts of operating systems.